# .htaccess - Is there a caching wait?

Tags: caching, .htaccess

Been writing some mod_rewrites on a .htaccess file. Just wondering if the file takes any amount of time to load in? Or is it pretty much instantanous as soon as you upload it to the server?

My server is a Linux Server on a Shared Hosting Domain.

Thanks in advance. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only latency I know of is the fact that Apache looks for every single directory under your web root to see if a .httaccess has been created. This is the reason Apache suggests us to avoid .htaccess in instances where a direct edit of httpd.conf is possible.

Comment: R, Where can I find the httpd.conf file (If it has been edited or added to the FTP)?

Comment: I'm afraid you can't, since you mentioned that you're on a shared hosting :(

Comment: Gotchya. So its a guessing game as such then? Thanks for your help though :)